# SELECT TOP COALESCE and bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ignore the practicality of the following sql query

```
DECLARE @limit BIGINT

SELECT TOP (COALESCE(@limit, 9223372036854775807))
    *
FROM
    sometable
```

It warns that

> The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer.

Why doesn't it work but the following works?

```
SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807
    *
FROM
    sometable
```

And `COALESCE(@limit, 9223372036854775807)` is indeed `9223372036854775807` when `@limit` is null?

I know that changing `COALESCE` to `ISNULL` works but I want to know the reason.

Comment: TOP () must be INTEGER. Your parameter is BIGINT.  Even if you declare @limit as INTEGER, the result of COALESCE(@limit, 9223372036854775807)  will still be big int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223927%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

> Specifying bigint Constants
>
> Whole number constants that are outside the range supported by the int
>   data type continue to be interpreted as numeric, with a scale of 0 and
>   a precision sufficient to hold the value specified. For example, the
>   constant 3000000000 is interpreted as numeric. These numeric constants
>   are implicitly convertible to bigint and can be assigned to bigint
>   columns and variables:

```
DECLARE @limit bigint
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(COALESCE(@limit, 9223372036854775807),'BaseType') 
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(9223372036854775807, 'BaseType') BaseType
```

shows that 9223372036854775807 is `numeric`, so the return value of coalesce is numeric. Whereas

```
DECLARE @limit bigint
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ISNULL(@limit, 9223372036854775807),'BaseType')
```

gives `bigint`. Difference being `ISNULL` return value has the data type of the first expression, but `COALESCE` return value has the highest data type.

```
SELECT TOP (cast(COALESCE(@limit, 9223372036854775807) as bigint))
    *
FROM
    tbl
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
  @x AS VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
  @y AS VARCHAR(10) = '1234567890';

SELECT
  COALESCE(@x, @y) AS COALESCExy, COALESCE(@y, @x)
    AS COALESCEyx,
  ISNULL(@x, @y) AS ISNULLxy, ISNULL(@y, @x)
    AS ISNULLyx;
```

Output:

```
COALESCExy      COALESCEyx      ISNULLxy        ISNULLyx
----------      ----------      --------        ----------
1234567890      1234567890      123             1234567890
```

Notice that with COALESCE, regardless of which input is specified first, the type of the output is VARCHAR(10)—the one with the higher precedence. However, with **ISNULL, the type of the output is determined by the first input**. So when the first input is of a VARCHAR(3) data type (the expression aliased as ISNULLxy), the output is VARCHAR(3). As a result, the returned value that originated in the input @y is truncated after three characters.That means isnull would not change the type, but coalesce would.

Comment: but @limit and 9223372036854775807 are both bigint, no?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that 9223372036854775807 is a numeric instead of a bigint

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223927(v=sql.80).aspx

> Whole number constants that are outside the range supported by the int data type continue to be interpreted as numeric, with a scale of 0 and a precision sufficient to hold the value specified

So we need to explicitly cast it to bigint

```
DECLARE @limit BIGINT

SELECT TOP (COALESCE(@limit, CAST(9223372036854775807 AS BIGINT)))
    *
FROM
    sometable
```